# SQL Server: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

If I run the SQL query below; I get the following error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

`COLUMNA` contains only numbers (negative and positive) including fields with maximal up to two digits after the decimal and is stored as dot decimal.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('st00_TABLEA','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [st00_TABLEA]
SELECT 
    COLUMNA AS COLUMNA_s
    ,CASE WHEN [COLUMNA] = '' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),REPLACE([COLUMNA],',','.')) END AS COLUMNA
INTO st00_TABLEA
FROM dbosu.TABLEA;
```

I also tried the following, but still same problem:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('st00_TABLEA','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [st00_TABLEA]
SELECT 
    COLUMNA AS COLUMNA_s
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),COLUMNA) AS COLUMNA
INTO st00_TABLEA
FROM dbosu.TABLEA;
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You might need to revise the data in the column, but anyway you can do one of the following:-

1- check if it is numeric then convert it else put another value like 0

```
Select COLUMNA AS COLUMNA_s, CASE WHEN Isnumeric(COLUMNA) = 1
THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),COLUMNA) 
ELSE 0 END AS COLUMNA
```

2- select only numeric values from the column

```
SELECT COLUMNA AS COLUMNA_s ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),COLUMNA) AS COLUMNA
where Isnumeric(COLUMNA) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input; it gives me another error now however:

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. 

So in your query you check whether the cells are numeric; if yes; then convert them.

What I don't understand though; COLUMNA actually has only numeric values in the table (both negative and posit numbers, as well as zeros). Do you know why the check for isnumeric still is necessary?

Comment: you are welcome.. data needs to be investigated somehow.. you can use the output from this query and compare it with the original data in the table, if you found difference in a value, that value might be the problem

Answer (score 15):

In case of float values with characters 'e' '+' it errors out if we try to convert in decimal. ('2.81104e+006'). It still pass ISNUMERIC test.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('2.81104e+006')
```

returns `1`.

```
SELECT convert(decimal(15,2), '2.81104e+006')
```

returns

> error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

And

```
SELECT try_convert(decimal(15,2), '2.81104e+006')
```

returns `NULL`.

```
SELECT convert(float, '2.81104e+006')
```

returns the correct value `2811040`.

Comment: This saved me in an XML parsing situation where scientific notation appears once in a while - Many thanks. 

    SELECT 
      ISNULL(DataRows.ID.value(N'(@SomeValThatFails)[1]','DECIMAL(6,5)'), -1),
      ISNULL(DataRows.ID.value(N'(@SomeOtherValThatWorks)[1]','FLOAT'), -1)
    FROM @XML.nodes('./XMLNodes') AS DataRows(ID)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this error while converting from nvarchar to float.
What I had to do was to use the `LEFT` function on the nvarchar field.

Example: `Left(Field,4)`

Basically, the query will look like:

```
Select convert(float,left(Field,4)) from TABLE
```

Just ridiculous that SQL would complicate it to this extent, while with C# it's a breeze!
Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: Thanks, i tried everything i could think off, nothing worked, i guess there is something else in the field. However i would recommend going higher than left(Field,4), i used left(Field,48) as i have defined the column as nvarchar(50)

Answer (score 1):

If your compatibility level is SQL Server 2012 (110) or higher, you can just use `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `CONVERT`.

```
SELECT
    TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), COLUMNA) AS COLUMNA
FROM
    dbosu.TABLEA;
```

`TRY_CONVERT` returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.