# SQL Server : error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

I am new to this and I am trying to learn more about SQL. I have this example and still not able to figure it out why I am getting this error:

```
DECLARE @xmlprice XML = '<price>1234567</price>'
DECLARE @price DECIMAL(19,4);

SET @price = @xmlprice.value('sum(price)', 'DECIMAL(19,4)');
```

I get the following error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Can you share with us what you found when you Google'd that error message and attempted to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Yes i did, but the funny thing is that when i reduce it to 6 digits it works when i try using 7 digits it failed. I did research on google but nothing relate it to this specific problem. The precision it suppose to work with 19 digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254298/sql-server-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-numeric)

Comment: I'm not an xml guy, but decimal(19,4) has a scale of 15 (digits to the left of the decimal). select len('price123456price') = 16.

Comment: Hi @Jayvi03 , Please convert @xmlprice.value('sum(price)') to decimal using SQL Cast or Convert function

Comment: that may be a solution but still does not clarify why it works with 6 digits and not with 7 digits even if i increase the decimal precision to 38

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that's a bug, but it's such a strange thing to do I'm not sure.  Normally you would project the XML values out first, and then aggregate them.

eg

```
select @xmlprice.value('(/price)[1]','decimal(19,4)');
```

This expression says to start at the root '/' and then find all the 'price' elements, pick the first one, and extract its value.

You may want to post this on the [SQL Server feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/) for the product team to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your recommendation, I cast my price value to decimal with a FLWOR Statement and Iteration (XQuery) before the sum.

```
DECLARE @xmlprice XML = '<price>1234567</price>'
DECLARE @price DECIMAL(19,4);

SET @price = @xmlprice.value('sum(for $price in //price return $price cast as xs:decimal?)', 'DECIMAL(19,4)');
```