# Error converting data type nvarchar(50) to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-update

I have a price column with the type of `NVARCHAR(50)`. Inside of this, I have data like `123,22` as a string and goes on. They are now string and I want to convert them to `decimal(18,2)` and I am trying to query this but giving me an error:

```
UPDATE reservations
SET price = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), price,105))
ALTER TABLE reservations
ALTER COLUMN price decimal(18, 2)
```

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I have run this code before for the `datetime` and it worked but for `decimal` I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254298/sql-server-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-numeric)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should replace **comma** to **dot** . For example ;

```
DECLARE @price AS NVARCHAR(50)=N'123,22'

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), REPLACE(@price,',','.'),105)
```

If we change your query according to this approach;

```
UPDATE reservations
SET price= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), REPLACE(price,',','.'),105))
ALTER TABLE reservations
ALTER COLUMN price decimal(18, 2)
```